# Download Content via Apex

Tags: apex

I'm trying to download bunch of content files from the console by executing apex scripts. I've got the IDs but failed to figure out the specific code. Can anyone drop by and take a look?

```
    List<ContentDocument> contentList = [SELECT Id, Title from ContentDocument where Id in ('0690y000006UXXX',
    '0690y000006XXXXX');

    for(ContentDocument c : contentList){
      --snip-- 
      should be iterating the content file and download each one of them
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to "download" a file using apex code. What if this is being run in trigger? You might want to use dataloader for this

Comment: I've been thinking about trigger for a while, but the reality is more like random request from different teams about downloading documents from different libraries. embedded coding stuff is not really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual data is stored in ContentVersion. The latest version link would be stored on content document. You then have to do a rest call to download your file.

```
List<ContentDocument> contentList = [SELECT Id, Title,LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocument where Id IN ('0697E000000g9lPQAQ')];

for(ContentDocument c : contentList){
    //do  GET call on
    '/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+ c.LatestPublishedVersionId+'/VersionData'
}
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

Comment: Hey Pranay, let me try this first. Thanks!

Comment: and to do multiple as a zip: http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/03/16/download-multiple-contentversion-files-as-zip/

Comment: Super! It works! Thanks go to you two!

Comment: @cropredy that is pretty good find.